# How to call Parse_page2 method for every item

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to call `parse_page2` method for every item. But every time i run this spider i am only getting single item per page so how do i call `parse_page2` method for every item.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from eScraper.items import EscraperItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class ESpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "atisundarSpider"

    allowed_domains = ["atisundar.com"]

    URLSList = []

    for n in range (1,20):

        URLSList.append('http://atisundar.com/collections/sarees?page=' + str(n))
        URLSList.append('http://atisundar.com/collections/salwar-suits?page=' + str(n))

    start_urls = URLSList

    def parse(self, response):

        item = EscraperItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="block product size-medium"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = EscraperItem()
            item['productDesc'] = "" 
            item['productSite'] = ["http://atisundar.com/"]
            item['productTitle'] = site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/@title').extract()
            item['productURL'] = ["http://atisundar.com" + site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/@href').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')]
            item['productPrice'] = site.select('.//p[@class="pricearea"]//span[@class="was-price"]/text()').extract() + site.select('.//p[@class="pricearea"]//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract() 
            item['productImage'] = [site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/img/@src').extract()[0].split('?')[0]] + [site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/img/@src').extract()[0].split('?')[0].replace("medium","grande")]
            item['image_urls'] = item['productImage']
            items.append(item)

            secondURL = "http://admin.atisundar.com/store/skuDetails?product_id=" + site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/text()').extract()[1].strip().split("#")[-1]

            request = Request(secondURL,
                      callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item 

            return request

    def parse_page2(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        #item['other_url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you are not using `CrawlSpider` functionality , i would recommend you to inherit your spider from `BaseSpider`

2) in `for` loop

```
for site in sites:
```

use `yield` rather then `return` , other wise it will break the loop in first iteration.

```
yield request
```

3)  in parse_page2 get `item` from `response.request.meta` instead from `response.meta`

```
item = response.request.meta['item']
```

it should work now.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from eScraper.items import EscraperItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class ESpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "atisundarSpider"

    allowed_domains = ["atisundar.com"]

    URLSList = []

    for n in range (1,20):

        URLSList.append('http://atisundar.com/collections/sarees?page=' + str(n))
        URLSList.append('http://atisundar.com/collections/salwar-suits?page=' + str(n))

    start_urls = URLSList

def parse(self, response):
    item = EscraperItem()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="block product size-medium"]')
    for site in sites:
        item = EscraperItem()
        item['productDesc'] = "" 
        item['productSite'] = ["http://atisundar.com/"]
        item['productTitle'] = site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/@title').extract()
        item['productURL'] = ["http://atisundar.com" + site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/@href').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')]
        item['productPrice'] = site.select('.//p[@class="pricearea"]//span[@class="was-price"]/text()').extract() + site.select('.//p[@class="pricearea"]//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract() 
        item['productImage'] = [site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/img/@src').extract()[0].split('?')[0]] + [site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/img/@src').extract()[0].split('?')[0].replace("medium","grande")]
        item['image_urls'] = item['productImage']
        secondURL = "http://admin.atisundar.com/store/skuDetails?product_id=" + site.select('.//div[@class="main"]/a/text()').extract()[1].strip().split("#")[-1]
        request = Request(secondURL,
                  callback=self.parse_page2)
        request.meta['item'] = item 
        yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):

    item = response.request.meta['item']
    #item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```